# Delete mesh groups that are on the interior

Tags: mesh, armature

I've brought a body model in from [Poser](https://www.posersoftware.com/). I made some modifications to the rig and it behaves well enough. However, when I move it, the teeth and belt loops stay behind:

[image]

On entering *Edit Mode*, the model is hiding the teeth:

[image]

Therefore, I cannot accurately isolate and delete the teeth mesh, as well as the belt loops. How can I go about deleting these objects? They seem to be the only objects that aren't parented to the armature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the editing mode. Press Alt+Z to see you through the mesh. Find the teeth, select one vertex, press Ctrl+L (all teeth will be selected) then you can remove the vertices. Repeat the same actions with belt loops.

Comment: Nice, I think you mean Ctrl + Z.

Comment: No, I wrote everything correctly. CTRL+Z - cancels the last action. CTRL+L - selects all mesh vertices that are directly connected to it, ALT+Z - makes the mesh translucent.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. Alt Z on my computer brings up a NVIDIA GeForce Experience panel. Maybe it was Shift Z that worked for me. I don't know. But I found the button you are talking about "Toggle X Ray"